# How to create a user account drop down settings menu using fa-fa fonts?

Tags: html, css

I like the look of this drop down menu fa-fa fonts provided as an example:
[image]

Here is what it looks like when clicked:

[image]

How could I do this with CSS? The current HTML code I am using is:

```
<div class="btn-group open">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <span class="fa fa-caret-down" title="Toggle dropdown menu"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i> Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> Delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban fa-fw"></i> Ban</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> Make admin</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a straightforward example in [the Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split):

```
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Split button -->
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```